# UIImagePickerController in iOS7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode5

[image]

How to get `UIImagePickerController` in iOS 7 Look like the same screen that show in the attached screen shot with out using Overlay Controller.

This is the code am using for picker controller.

```
UIImagePickerController  *eImagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
eImagePickerController.delegate=self;


eImagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
eImagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
eImagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
eImagePickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
eImagePickerController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
eImagePickerController.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
eImagePickerController.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
eImagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(eImagePickerController.cameraViewTransform, CAMERA_TRANSFORM_X, CAMERA_TRANSFORM_Y);

[self presentViewController:eImagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The issue is shown in attached screenshot
[image]

Comment: And what is not working with the code you post, please elaborate more about the issue you are having.

Comment: No need to yell. But what to you mean with: top bar likr navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will present the [`UIImagePickerController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) in a way that resembles the screenshot given.

```
UIImagePickerController  *eImagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
eImagePickerController.delegate = self;

eImagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
eImagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
eImagePickerController.cameraDevice= UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
eImagePickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
eImagePickerController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

[self presentViewController:eImagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Just make sure that you hide the status bar or it will be displayed in the [`UIImagePickerController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) as well.